# Passing argument to python handler

Tags: python, google-app-engine, handler, webapp2

I am calling on a handler through a link in a table value , like this:

```
<td><a id="{{ test['test_name'] }}" href="/regex" >{{ test['test_name'] }}</a></td>
```

The handler has a SQL query that I want to run based on the id, or value of the cell, so when the link is clicked it send the unique name. I tried to read webapp2 documentation on URI routing but couldn't understand how to apply it to my problem.

Comment: I am using this when creating the handler route: ('/regex/(\d+)', Handler), but when I call it in my href link it picks up the test['test_name'] in the url

Comment: how do i properly call it from my href? i have it as href = "/regex/{{ test['test_name'] }}"

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation on [URI Routing](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html), the example shows:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/', HomeHandler),
    (r'/products', ProductListHandler),
    (r'/products/(\d+)', ProductHandler),
])
```

For your handler, you could use:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/regex/<test>', RegexHandler),
])
```

Then you would call it using:

```
<a href="/regex/{{ test['test_name'] }}" >{{ test['test_name'] }}</a>
```

(The `id="..."` attribute is not passed as part of the URL, it's an HTML attribute.)

Note: you may need to URL-encode the parameter `test['test_name']`.